# How to insert value in array by increasing index in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, insert

I have an array like this:

```
var Array = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

How can i use `for()` loop to insert new values to it, the index of value start from index 0 and it `+1` each time i insert new value.

For example

```
Array.insert("e", at: 0) //["e","a","b","c","d"]
Array.insert("f", at: ???) //["e","f","a","b","c","d"]
```

Comment: Do you mean insert(_:at:) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641389-insert

Answer (score 1):

You can insert another array at 0th index using [`insert(contentsOf:at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641389-insert)

```
var Array = ["a","b","c","d"]

Array.insert(contentsOf: ["e","f","g","h"], at: 0) //["e", "f", "g", "h", "a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

If you want to use for loop then you can use this

```
for (index,str) in ["e","f","g","h"].enumerated()
{
   Array.insert(str, at: index)
}
```

Comment: Simpler `for` loop: `for str in ["e","f","g","h"].reversed() { array.insert(str, at: 0) }`.